# Can I save a image dynamically and use it in layouts?

Tags: android

I have a small query, is it possible to get an image dynamically every-time the app is launched over the internet and then that Image can be used to be shown on UI(via xml file)please let me know if this can be achieved in android and with any sample code.
Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys found a better solution

```
try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the best way to do it is to load image via HTTP GET, store it in `Bitmap` object and inject programmatically into `ImageView` element defined in layout.

You can't override resource image so you cant use `@drawable`.

Here you have `loadBitmap` method that loads image by url and stores it in `Bitmap`: [`How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472175/223386)

Next thing is to inject it into `ImageView`:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap("http://www.android.com/images/logo.png");
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: The method loadBitmap(String) is undefined for the type

Comment: What do you mean ? Did you copy code from the question a have linked ?

Comment: Thanks mate. But I am finding issues while finally {
         closeStream(in);
         closeStream(out);
     }

Answer (score 0):

Not possible through XML.

I'd recommend having a placebo bitmap also in case there is no Internet access available at the time. Use AsyncTask when downloading.

```
new GetAndSetBitmap.execute(url)

private class GetAndSetBitmap extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
   protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls)
       {
          Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmap(url[0]);
          // Used the loadBitmap from other answer. Anything goes wrong 
          // load a local resource with the same dimensions.
          return bitmap;
       }
    @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm)
       {
         yourImageView.setImageBitMap(bm);
       }
}
```